# What -W values in gcc correspond to which actual warnings?

Tags: c++, gcc

Preamble: I know, disabling warnings is not a good idea. Anyway, I have a technical question about this.

---

Using GCC 3.3.6, I get the following warning:

```
choosing ... over ... because conversion sequence for the argument is better.
```

Now, I want to disable this warning as described in [gcc warning options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) by providing an argument like

```
-Wno-theNameOfTheWarning
```

But I don't know the name of the warning. **How can I find out the name of the option that disables this warning?**

---

I am not able to fix the warning, because it occurs in a header of an external library that can not be changed. It is in boost serialization (`rx(s, count)`):

```
template<class Archive, class Container, class InputFunction, class R>
inline void load_collection(Archive & ar, Container &s)
{
    s.clear();
    // retrieve number of elements
    collection_size_type count;
    unsigned int item_version;
    ar >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(count);
    if(3 < ar.get_library_version())
        ar >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(item_version);
    else
        item_version = 0;
    R rx;
    rx(s, count);
    std::size_t c = count;
    InputFunction ifunc;
    while(c-- > 0){
        ifunc(ar, s, item_version);
    }
}
```

---

I have already tried `#pragma GCC system_header` but this had no effect. Using `-isystem` instead of `-I` also does not work.

The general question remains is: I know the text of the warning message. But I do not know the correlation to the [gcc warning options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Comment: It would be very helpful, and make the question more complete, if you actually included some code that triggers this warning.

Comment: ... Why are you still using gcc 3.3?

Comment: We migrate to an up-to-date gcc-version, but we still have to support gcc 3.3 for some time.

Comment: Let's see, you can't use a halfway modern version of gcc, you have to use it with a third-party library that probably wasn't written to support 3.3....how badly do you want to get rid of the warning?  It might be better just to live with it.

Comment: @Seb: What's the warnings you've got?

Comment: @David Thornley There is only this one warning left in a large code base. We want to activate "treat warnings as errors", but need to fix this one first.

Comment: @SebastianK: So, in order to clear all the errors, you're trying to tell the compiler not to mention warnings?  This doesn't seem wrong to you?

Comment: @John Dibling I do not understand your comment. There are no errors, many warnings are enabled, we want to treat warnings as errors. Just one warning in an external header remains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find out what option is associated with a given warning by using the `-fdiagnostics-show-option` option:

```
$ gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wall foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:3: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
```

And my two cents about this: assuming there's no way to actually fix the warning, hopefully you can manage to disable the warning for a minimal amount of compilation, so that if you make a similar mistake in your own code, you'll be warned.

Edit: This appears to be `-Wconversion`. (Found by poking in the source - you can just grep for some of the warning text, and find the call to `warning( OPT_W_conversion, ...`.)

Comment: Unfortunately, in GCC 3.3.6 this option is not available.

Comment: @SebastianK: Well, that's awkward. Hopefully `-isystem` will work out for you, but if it doesn't... I'd try and take your code somewhere else and compile with a newer version of GCC. It looks like you can probably make a pretty minimal test case that'll produce the warning?

Comment: @SebastianK: I think I found it for you... but I'd still try and do what you can to avoid actually turning off warnings, of course!

Comment: @Jefromi Thanks for your help, but neither `-isystem` nor `-Wno-conversion` disable the warning.

Comment: @SebastianK: That's... odd. That was the only place I found that given warning text in the source. I think I've done about all I can do without you actually providing code which provokes the warning.

Comment: I fixed the warning in the external library, this really wasn't a big issue. I had clearly preferred to leave it untouched, but now, changing it seems to be the best option. Thanks, Jefromi.

Comment: @Jefromi: when you checked the source, did you check the gcc3 source or the gcc4 source?

Comment: @Bill: I did look at gcc4 source, but then I looked at the gcc3 documentation and saw that the warning was available then too, with basically the same description.

Comment: @Jefromi: Excellent!  I don't have access to gcc3 here, and don't know if those ever change from version to version.

Answer (score 5):

How about change your code to remove the warning?  It sounds like you probably should cast one of your parameters to a specific type instead of having the compiler choose which cast to do.

Comment: This is not possible, because it occurs in an external library. For more details, I edited my original question.

Comment: @Sebastian: Curious that you say both it's not possible and "I fixed the warning in the external library, this really wasn't a big issue." ;)

Comment: @Roger Pate :) Fixing it was not a big issue, but changing it created additional effort due to internal processes, that I tried to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

Two points:
You should leave warnings on - compiler warnings bode ill later on - crashes, corruption, etc.

The used to be the -Wnotanidiot flag.  This was around in late version 2.9 ... 3.o of gcc. 
I don't know if it still works, but this warning would qualify.

Comment: In case someone thinks I'm being a jerk. Some warnings for some programmers have little merit. Phil Edwards created an add-on. It was available. Whether it is apropos for this discussion you can decide, but it did exist. I played with it myself.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to the question, "How can I find out the name of the option that disables this warning?" is "Read the source of the compiler."